# how to call a variable inside a class in ionic4?

Tags: css, sass, ionic4

its possible to call a variable created in variables.scss inside a class?

i tried the code bellow and does not work

this is my variables.scss:

```
$test : (
  color: purple,
  font-style: normal,
  font-weight: normal,
  font-size: 13px
  );
```

and this is my html(ionic4)

```html
<ion-label class="test">Just testing!</ion-label>
<h1 class="test">Testing again</h1>
```

How i can solve this?

Comment: I'm curious why you wouldn't just make a class?

Comment: to avoid code repetition

Comment: Why not just make a class with those attributes, and apply the class when those styles are needed instead off also applying those styles in another class/selector? In your scenario, the css would be duplicated when it's compiled.

Comment: like this? `.test{ $test}`

Answer (score 0):

You can't call a variable of multiple style attributes from a class, but you can extend another class.

```
.test {
  color: purple;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.another {
  @extend .test;
}
```

[Working Prototype](https://codepen.io/RadicalCaitlin/pen/wLqrgE)

More info here: https://coderwall.com/p/7p7w2a/when-to-use-sass-mixins-extends-and-variables

Comment: hmm so i cant store more than one style in sass variable and apply to a class?

Answer (score -1):

after alot research, I came to the conclusion that the best way to solve is to create a mixin

like this:

```
@mixin test{
  color: purple;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 13px;
  }

.test{
  @include test();
}
```

Comment: You said you wanted to reduce duplication, but a mixin duplicates it. Every place you use @include it will inject a full copy of the mixin into the final css: https://codepen.io/rtpHarry/pen/zVdVEE -

Comment: but creating a mixin, I'll just need to add the class where I need it

Comment: ok but you're making the client download bigger just to apply a shortcut on the development side

Comment: I don't understand the development side shortcut you're expecting. Can you explain it? Also, to use the DRY principal, you should us extends instead of mixins. Mixins duplicate every place they are called on compile; extends create a multi-selector on compilation, so the extended styles are only written once.